# Unknown command: opencv_createsamples - Some commands work, some does not

Tags: python, homebrew, opencv

**Problem**

Upon using *OpenCV* commands, I realized my system recognizes only a fraction.

Command:

```sh
opencv_createsamples
```

Output:

```sh
Unknown command: opencv_createsamples
```

**Some OpenCV commands get recognized.** For example here:

Command:

```sh
opencv_version
```

Output:

```sh
4.5.0
```

**Notes:**
I installed *OpenCV* through *Homebrew*. Since some of the work, and some not, it makes me believe that the Homebrew version did not provide all the necessary binaries, or if it did, then some links were not properly equipped.

I have attempted to build OpenCV from source, but it didn't grant me the binaries I was looking for. However, when I look through the build folder created, the `bin` folder doesn't contain the `opencv_createsamples` binary.

Comment: which version of opencv u are using ? newer than 3.x ?

Comment: Indeed, as the `opencv_version` output shows, I am currently using version "4.5.0."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some c api commands were deprecated like `opencv_createsamples` in the versions of opencv newer than 3.x.

If you really want to use that, you can temporarily install an old version. Also this command is a temporary command which you will not use always. Just get the samples in old version and pass the newer version.

Comment: If you are on macOS, this is simple as:

```bash
brew install opencv@3 && brew link --overwrite opencv@3
```